# Drupal 8 with React render out components in a single json output

Tags: reactjs, drupal, drupal-8

The plan is for me to use Drupal being the engine to output rest api data and the cms handling for the end user to add/delete/edit content.

React to handle the view layer and display how each page should look.

Is there a way with Drupal 8 to output in the rest api exactly what components/modules that the end user would like to use per each page? Rather than just a single node.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean, you want to be able to choose the components used by React from the Drupal Backend? In this case, why not create a Taxonomy containing the components and send that along with the node?

Comment: Basically have a json that does this per each page:

```
data [{
  "component": "componentOne",
  "title": "Title One",
  "cta": "Click here",
  "ctaLink": "http://espn.com"
},{
  "component": "componentTwo",
  "title": "Title One",
"copy": "Lorem ipsum"
}]

```